# phpexcel not outputing anything

Tags: php, phpexcel

Below is my simple test php. When I run this nothing at all happens.

```
require_once('/var/www/html/Classes/PHPExcel.php');

$excel = new PHPExcel();

$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A1','Hello')
    ->setCellValue('B1','World');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="/var/www/html/Examples/test.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Any ideas of why this does not work. No redirect at all and not file either.

Answer (score 0):

With  skimming [PHPEXCEL documentation](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home) sample something like the following could work :

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
require_once('/var/www/html/Classes/PHPExcel.php');

$sheet = array(
    array(
      'a1 Hello',
      'b1 World',
      'c1 here',
      'd1 test',
    )
  );

  $doc = new PHPExcel();
  $doc->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

  $doc->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($sheet, null, 'A1');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="your_name.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

  // Do your stuff here
  $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($doc, 'Excel5');

$writer->save('php://output');
?>
```

**Important Note** Dont kill the process by exit();